# calling instance action from terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have this action check_num_reports_on_need in the need model , I need to test it so I want to call it from the terminal on a specific Need .. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open up rails console:

   ```
   $ rails c
   ```
2. Inside console load or create instance of a model:

   ```
   my_model = MyModel.create( ... )
   ```
3. Start testing the method by calling it on an instance:

   ```
   my_model.check_num_reports_on_need # => some value
   ```
4. Once changed the code in the `check_num_reports_on_need` method definition, reload console environment by calling:

   ```
   reload!
   ```